# What does adding the alignment declaration specifier to a return type do?

Tags: c++

I saw some source code that defined a function with a return type that had an alignment specifier like so (For MSVC++):

```
__declspec(align(SOMEALIGN)) return_type function_name() { ... }
```

I've tested with an alignment of 128 and checked the addresses of locals inside the function. I've checked the invocation of the function and the temporary local allocated if I change the `return_type` to a fairly large struct, and checked the address of the function. None of which were aligned. So I want to know, what exactly becomes aligned?

Comment: `__declspec` is a compiler extension, so you have to check your compiler's manual. Note that over-alignment may not be supported on your platform.

Comment: Yeah I read the page [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65(v=vs.80).aspx) Sorry I didn't mention that.